# How to use the baposter grid?

Tags: posters, baposter, a0poster

I have created a poster using `baposter` that has a beautiful background that I want to show more of. Some columns do not have enough text to go all the way to the bottom of the poster, so I want to move the complete column downwards to leave some space in the middle of the poster so that one can see the background clearer. For this I suppose using the grid could help, but I haven't found anywhere that shows how to use it. Here is an example of how it looks like: I want to move the second header lower.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
{grid=true,
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
background=none, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=black, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}

\headerbox{Intro}{name=intro,column=0,row=0}{
bla bla bla
 }

\headerbox{end}{name=end,column=0,below=intro}{
bla bla bla}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

So what I want is to create some space between the two headerboxes, instead of writing `below=intro`, to let there be some blank space.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm inclined to delete this question, maybe because I am completely inept with computers and the answer to this was actually obvious. I just realised  that rows can take non-integer values, and hence, one can align the headerboxes by setting the row to a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Don't delete it.

Comment: The page is not only to answer questions of people's questions but also for future users as  a source of knowledge, so those users don't have to ask questions. Post your solution as an answer.